# NODE_ENV is undefined after running the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am unsure why when i try to log `process.env.NODE_ENV`, its **undefined** , after setting up the NODE_ENV in my bash profile

```
echo export NODE_ENV=production >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I can see the value being set in my bash_profile, after running the above command.

Comment: How are you running the Node script? If it’s not through a bash login shell, it’s not going to read your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @Ryan its just 'npm start' in my terminal

Comment: Does `NODE_ENV=production npm start` work?

Comment: @Ryan i take back my previous comment, i was running it through my WebStorm IDE terminal and this doesn't pick up the env. But running it through the terminal does output the env

Comment: For WebStorm, look at the `Run/Debug Configuration` for your project. There is an environment variables section there: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html